# How to convert RAW formated Pendrive back to NTFS File system?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1

How to convert RAW formated Pendrive back to NTFS File system ???

Please let me know if anyone has solution.

I am unable to transfer any data to my pen drive.

Whenever I connect it to my Laptop it shows pop up that Format Needed

But windows is unable to complete the format.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

1. Launch Computer Management: Start > Right-Click 'Computer' > Manage.
   Under 'Storage', select 'Disk Management'. Note which disk is your pen drive.
2. Launch an elevated command prompt: Start > Run, type 'cmd', then right-click CMD and select 'Run as Administrator'.
3. Type: 'diskpart', 'list disk', 'select disk [Whichever disk you noted in step 1]', 'list disk' (The selected disk will now have an astrisk (*) next to it), 'online disk', 'clean', 'convert mbr'.
4. In the Computer Management window, right-click 'Disk Managmement' and select 'Rescan Disks'.
5. Create new partitions as desired.

Comment: I tried it but didn't work.. 

Shows error like...

DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
See the System Event Log for more information

Comment: Ew. I/O device error. Investigate that. Start in your event logs. It'll be unrelated to this question so you won't get an answer here, but google is your friend.